# C# TCP Listen and Connect on the same Local Port

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a C# Console Application where I'm trying to implement TCP Hole Punching.

I need to listen on a Local Port and at the same time (simultaneously/asynchronously) connect to 2 different remote hosts (in reality a remote hosts public and private endpoints) using the same Local Port.

As I understand I somehow need to bind the Sockets/Ports but I can't figure this out in C#.

There's the TCPListener, TCPClient and Socket classes and I don't know which ones to use to accomplish what I need.

I'm following this guide http://www.bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/index.html Chapter 4.2

> 3. From the same local TCP ports that *A* and *B* (Clients) used to register with (Server) *S*,  *A* and *B* each asynchronously make outgoing connection attempts to the other's public and private endpoints as reported by *S*, while simultaneously listening for incoming connections on their respective local TCP ports.

I've already implemented the server part using NodeJS and it's working fine, I'm struggling with the Local Port stuff mentioned above.

Comment: Is it possible that `their respective local TCP ports` is not the same as the ones used to connect to _S_? If yes which other Port is it?

Comment: If you have two threads, are you getting an error trying to bind the listener and the TcpClient to the same port?

Comment: I don't think I'm using separate threads, I'm running them using Tasks and calling Task.WaitAll() so themethod with the listener and the method with the TCPClient run at the same time, My issue is with actually telling the TCPClient to use/bind to the same local port as the listener. I posted this yesterday where you can see the code used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930824/c-sharp-tcp-hole-punching-clients-not-connecting

Comment: Well if you explicity tell client A to connect to the server on say port '25000', when the actual connection is established, if you check the properties, it usually says it is connected on a different port. Is that the port you're using for the 'private' connection?

Comment: I don't need to tell it which port to use to connect to the server, I simply need to know which 'local' port it used to connect to the server so I can later use it to listen and connect to the other client.

Comment: Well in any case, to connect to the server, have you identified the 'private' and 'public' endpoints?

Comment: Of course, Both Clients already have the others Public and Local endpoints, I don't have any issue with that, The issue is with listening and sending requests from the same local port used to connect to the server. (I don't think there's a difference between private and local, they're the same thing. Correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: They must be different. That tutorial explicitly makes a distinction between `public endpoint` and `private endpoint`, as they state that you need to be performing *three* operations. Connect, connect, listen. So `public` and `private` should have somewhat different details. Also you might not want to do a `Task.WaitAll`, maybe use your own threads or simply a different method.

Comment: I know there's a difference between the public and private endpoints but the private endpoint can also be referred to as the local endpoint.

Comment: I see. Well if you have all the information correct and the clients are receiving it, maybe try a different method of connecting. Just for testing, maybe try a global boolean, and then run the 3 methods separately with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or something similar. Set the bool to true if any of the 3 operations connect successfully, and maybe put them in a for/while loop so they attempt to connect several times.

Comment: As you can see in the code I do have a global boolean `clients_are_connected` and they should be set to true if anything connects, but for some reason they don't get bound to the same local/private port.

Comment: What do you mean by they don't get bound to the same local/private port? Is there an error? It would be easier if you could produce an error or something.

Comment: Did you read the full other question? `Client A's local port used to connect to the server is 52974, and the listener actually uses that port (Client A output Line 14), but the one being used to try to connect to the other client is in one case 53025 (Line 13) and in one case 53024 (Line 17). (remember we're trying to connect to the second clients local "and" remote endpoints, therefore the 2 tries).`

Comment: Yes that's what I was mentioning earlier. If you check the connection properties, Windows will report that it has connected to a different local port. So if you tell it port 52974, and check the connection, it may not actually say it is connected on that port. I'm just not understanding what actually happens when you try this. In your other post I see `Someone connected to the socket!.127.0.0.1:53025`. That should only be possible if you've somehow connected *a client to itself*.

Comment: I don't understand how the client could make a connection to it's own listener if it's supposed to connect to the other clients public and private endpoints.

Comment: Well are you listening on localhost and trying to connect to localhost?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: Not anymore, I changed it to listen to the private ip used to connect to the server, but even if I am, the port is different, I'm trying to connect to the private and public port of the other client not my own private and public port I used to connect to the server. (this seems to become a really long thread which is not what the comments are for, can we continue the discussion elsewhere? I can't move it to chat since I only have 19 reputation and you need 20 to do it, maybe you can?)

Comment: I don't know if I can but you should be able to now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115216/discussion-between-effy-and-pay).

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that TCP only allows a 1-2-1 connection between client and server and ports. The only way to setup the multiple connections is to create two different sockets.

The TCP hole punching you're referring too I have tried before. You need to basically use the relay server to tell both A and B how to connect.. So do as follows:

1) Client A connects to Server on one port

2) Server tells Client B your IP and the port (this will be a new connection you will be setting up, different to your connection to the server)

3) Server tells Client A the IP and Port that Client B will be using

4) Client A uses the info provided to create a new connection directly to client B

5) Client B uses its info about your "new" connection to try and accept the incoming request

6) It might fail to handshake a couple of times due to latency, so build in some sort of repeater to keep trying the connection

7) You eventually should have a direct connection to B

Comment: Ther Server part is already fully implement and both clients do get the info of the other client, the issue I'm having is connecting the 2 clients, and as I understand you can't just `uses its info about your "new" connection to try and accept the incoming request` instead both need to listen _and_ make requests originating from the same local port used to connect to the server (the connection to the server can be terminated at this point), this means somehow binding the tcplistener and tcpclient socket to the same local port. If you've implemented this before, could you share the code?

Comment: I guess what you're suggesting is that one client always listens, and one client is the one that tries to connect to the other client, I don't think that would work since the way Hole Punching works is that the Firewall sees a request coming from the same endpoint a request was sent out to and lets it threw / connects them creating the connection, so both clients need to try and connect as listen in order for it to work.

Comment: My way of dealing with it was using a Duplex WCF NetTCP service for a connection from Client A to a relay server.. (and the same running on B)

Then use methods on there to call the server from A and callback to B.. Then use TCP sockets to drive the connection process between A and B..